# Append Rows to Pandas Dataframe in While loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a function that calculates the projected population per year based on values in different columns (these columns are not shown for simplicity).

How do I append these rows to the dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'state': ['Ohio','New York'],
'year': [2000,2000],
'pop': [2.5,3.6]
}
census = pd.DataFrame(data)

def projected_pop_by_year(s):
    new_census = pd.DataFrame()
    current_pop = census[census['state'] == s]['pop'].values[0]
    current_year = census[census['state'] == s]['year'].values[0]
    i = 0; count = 1
    while (i + 1) <= current_pop:
        projected_pop = None # some calculations
        data = {
            'state' : [s],
            'year' :  [current_year + count],
            'pop': [projected_pop]
        }
        print((pd.DataFrame(data)))
        i += 1; count += 1


projected_pop_by_year("Ohio")
```

Desired output:

```
| State    | Year | Pop   |
|----------|------|-------|
| Ohio     | 2000 | 2.5   |
| New York | 2000 | 3.6   |
| Ohio     | 2001 | None  |
| Ohio     | 2002 | None  |
```

I tried declaring a new dataframe outside the function with `global new_census` and appending the rows with `new_census.append(pd.DataFrame(data))`. The code I had didn't work. I tried `pd.concat`. That didn't work. I tried declaring a new dataframe inside the function. That didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def projected_pop_by_year(s):
    new_census = pd.DataFrame()
    current_pop = census[census['state'] == s]['pop'].values[0]
    current_year = census[census['state'] == s]['year'].values[0]
    i = 0; count = 1
    my_list = []
    while (i + 1) <= current_pop:

         projected_pop = None # some calculations
         data = {
             'state' : [s],
             'year' :  [current_year + count],
             'pop': [projected_pop]
         }
         my_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
         #print(pd.DataFrame(data))
         i += 1; count += 1
    my_list = pd.concat(my_list)
    print(census.append(pd.DataFrame(my_list)))
projected_pop_by_year("Ohio")

      state  year   pop
0      Ohio  2000   2.5
1  New York  2000   3.6
0      Ohio  2001  None
0      Ohio  2002  None
```

**Explaination** *Make a list before the while Loop and save the output of the while loop by appending the list. Finally concat them together and apend with the original `census` dataframe.*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways for adding rows to a Pandas DataFrame. When you know how to add the row, you can do it in a while/for loop in a way that matches your requirements. You can find different ways of adding a row to a Pandas DataFrame here:

https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-add-rows-in-a-dataframe-using-dataframe-append-loc-iloc/